# Updates: keep panels pages, views, etc.. updated via hook_update_n?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, updating

im having a little trouble keeping a project update.

I track the code via a private git repo, and for each update I follow those steps (first on stagin, then on production):

- update all the 3rd pars modules (from drupal.org)
- Update database (via drush updb)

Then if everything is ok:

- update my modules (via git repo)
- update database (drush again)

All works perfectly, except for pages/views exported via Features module: in my module i hav a function like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_default_page_manager_pages().
 */
function mymodule_default_page_manager_pages() {
    // Second page...
    $page = new stdClass();
    // page definition, display, etc..
    $pages['page_machine_name'] = $page;

    // Second page...
    $page = new stdClass();
    // page definition, display, etc..
    $pages['page_machine_name'] = $page;

    return $pages;
}
```

The structure is the same for views.

I noticed that if i update that function changing something in a previous declared (and imported) page (add a pane, change a configuration on a content, etc..), this one wont get updated! (yeah, i flushed the cache different times both via UI and via drush)

Am I doing something wrong? There is a specific way to update those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this can not be the best solution but it works:

```
function mymodule_update_7001(&$sandbox) {
  // Views.
  if (is_callable('views_save_view')) {
    $views = module_invoke_all('views_default_views');
    foreach ($views AS $view_object) {
      views_delete_view($view_object);
    }
    // Rebuild it.
    $views = module_invoke_all('views_default_views');
    foreach ($views AS $view_object) {
      views_save_view($view_object);
    }
  }

  // Pages
  module_load_include('inc', 'page_manager', 'plugins/tasks/page');
  if (is_callable('page_manager_page_save')) {
    $pages = module_invoke_all('default_page_manager_pages');
    foreach ($pages AS $page_object) {
      page_manager_page_delete($page_object);
    }
    // Rebuild it
    $pages = module_invoke_all('default_page_manager_pages');
    foreach ($pages AS $page_object) {
      page_manager_page_save($page_object);
    }
  }
}
```

Basically just keep updated the views and pages definitions (`views_default_views` and `default_page_manager_pages`), the delete and rebuild them.

Obviously, this remove all customizations done via the Drupal's UI, so only do it for the views and pages you need to update!